# is async/await allow other tasks to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Hi everyone i hope you guys doing well and sorry for the stupid question, I just wondering does async/await allow other tasks to run?.

I just read the [downside of async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#The_downsides_of_asyncawait) on MDN and there is a part that says "it does allow other tasks to continue to run in the meantime, but your own code is blocked." what does it mean by that? and is it only async/await can allow other tasks to run or can promises do that too? if so can you guys give me examples please? thank you in advance :)

Comment: the code within an `async` function  after `await ...` won't run until the promise it is awaiting resolves - which is exactly why it is useful - as for examples ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Also useful to understand [the event loop](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-event-loop-3dif)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a function hits an `await` statement, it runs the code on the right-hand-side to get the promise and then goes to sleep.

Other functions can run in the meantime, but any further lines in this one won't until the promise resolves.

That isn't a downside. That's the **point**.

```
async function example() {
    const result = await somethingFromAPromise();
    do_something_with(result);
}
```

If it didn't stop, then you wouldn't have the `result` to do something with on the next line.

---

What that section of documentation is saying, in a very long winded way, is that sometimes you'll have a situation like this:

```
async function example() {
    const result1 = await somethingFromAPromise();
    const result2 = await somethingFromAnotherPromise();
    do_something_with(resul1, result2);
}
```

… where you have two promises that **could** run in parallel because they are completely independant, but you don't start the second one until the first one is finished.

It also tells you how to mitigate that

```
async function example() {
    const result1Promise = somethingFromAPromise();
    const result2Promise = somethingFromAnotherPromise();
    const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all(result1Promise, result2Promise);
    do_something_with(resul1, result2);
}
```

Comment: cool its crystal clear now. thank you sir. and one more thing, is this applies for promise.then?

Comment: `async await` is syntactic sugar for promises so yes, `Promise.then` acts the same way: runs the code that produces the promise, "jumps over" the `then` body and only enters the `then` body when the promise resolves.

Comment: @KadekChresna `async-await` is just syntactic sugar over promises. Two consecutive `await` statements are same as two `then()` methods chained together, 2nd `then()` method won't execute until the promise returned by the 1st `then()` method - resolves.